# Take the difference between pivot table columns and compare to last column in previous row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table. Columns represent years, rows month. I want to create two tables containing the percent changes between every value and  its counterpart for the previous month.
I have managed to create a pivot table with the percentage changes, but logically, data is missing for January.
Instead, I would like to compare January with December, i.e. the last row of the previous column.
Thank you in advance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(12, 3)), columns=('2016', '2017', '2018'))
df.index.name = 'month'
df.index = df.index +1
print(df)
```

> ```
>          2016  2017  2018
> month                  
> 1        49    98     7
> 2        72    60    67
> 3        64    71    53
> 4        71    75    91
> 5        68    96    48
> 6        35    21    54
> 7        14    98     3
> 8        62    38    64
> 9        68    92    58
> 10       64    95    94
> 11       54    81     8
> 12       86    18    90
> ```

my current solution:

```
df_month_pctchange = df.pct_change(axis=0).mul(100)
print(df_month_pctchange)
```

> ```
>         2016   2017    2018
> month                      
> 1        NaN    NaN     NaN
> 2      46.94 -38.78  857.14
> 3     -11.11  18.33  -20.90
> 4      10.94   5.63   71.70
> 5      -4.23  28.00  -47.25
> 6     -48.53 -78.12   12.50
> 7     -60.00 366.67  -94.44
> 8     342.86 -61.22 2033.33
> 9       9.68 142.11   -9.38
> 10     -5.88   3.26   62.07
> 11    -15.62 -14.74  -91.49
> 12     59.26 -77.78 1025.00
> ```

Desired result:

> ```
>         2016   2017    2018
> month                      
> 1        NaN   7.35  -61.11
> 2      46.94 -38.78  857.14
> 3     -11.11  18.33  -20.90
> 4      10.94   5.63   71.70
> 5      -4.23  28.00  -47.25
> 6     -48.53 -78.12   12.50
> 7     -60.00 366.67  -94.44
> 8     342.86 -61.22 2033.33
> 9       9.68 142.11   -9.38
> 10     -5.88   3.26   62.07
> 11    -15.62 -14.74  -91.49
> 12     59.26 -77.78 1025.00
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select both first and last row of `df` with `iloc`, use `shift` on the last row to report value from 2016 to 2017 and so on, and do the calculation. Then set the result in the first row of `df_month_pctchange`

```
# your code
df_month_pctchange = df.pct_change(axis=0).mul(100)

# what to add to fill the missing values
df_month_pctchange.iloc[0] = (df.iloc[0]/df.iloc[-1].shift()-1)*100

print(df_month_pctchange)
#              2016        2017         2018
# month                                     
# 1             NaN   13.953488   -61.111111 # note it is 13.95 and not 7.35 in 2017
# 2       46.938776  -38.775510   857.142857
# 3      -11.111111   18.333333   -20.895522
# 4       10.937500    5.633803    71.698113
# 5       -4.225352   28.000000   -47.252747
# 6      -48.529412  -78.125000    12.500000
# 7      -60.000000  366.666667   -94.444444
# 8      342.857143  -61.224490  2033.333333
# 9        9.677419  142.105263    -9.375000
# 10      -5.882353    3.260870    62.068966
# 11     -15.625000  -14.736842   -91.489362
# 12      59.259259  -77.777778  1025.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! I have a lot to learn...